# processing GBs of data in kafka/storm

Tags: apache-storm

1. Is it possible to process GBs of data in Kafka/Storm as a single message?  File frequency is 30 minutes.
2. If not possible If I break the message into 1 MB each and then can I process it in Kafka/Storm?
3. My files is in SEGY format (Oil/gas domain) and I will call bin executables (written in c++) through storm to process this file.  Whether tuples can be formed successfully for this file format?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to use Storm to do this processing? Seems like a batch application may be more appropriate.

Regardless, you might be able to get it to work but I would recommend having your spout split the data up into more manageable chunks that can be processed by your bolts.

Comment: Hi Kit Menke, customer wants solution in kafka/storm.

Comment: Hi Kit Menke,  Bolt should just execute the bin executables to process seismic file.  After Spout can read successfully the file in chunks, whether Bolt can form tuples for this file format SEGY or SU(it is not readable format and also can't open in unix/windows)?  It contains collection of traces.  Please help.

Comment: So your spout could generate many tuples from the input file with two strings: header and trace data. Your bolt would receive the tuple (header + trace), pass it to the executable, get the output, and then send the output to somewhere (another bolt, storage, etc).